# How to use a trait as parameter of pymethod in PyO3

Tags: rust, pyo3

I am a beginner with PyO3, and I want to know how to use `Box<MyTrait>` as the input for a function in PyO3. I have already looked at the official tutorial [Appendix C: Trait bounds](https://pyo3.rs/v0.20.0/trait_bounds), but my situation is a bit different as I do not wish to call a python class within rust. Can someone provide some help? Much appreciated.

Here is a specific code example, I had defined a trait `SDF`:

```rust
pub trait SDF: Send + Sync {
    fn distance(&self, p: Vec3f) -> f32;
}
```

Now, I aim to implement a `Union` that can be invoked within python bounds:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

pub struct Union {
    a: Box<dyn SDF>,
    b: Box<dyn SDF>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl Union {
    pub fn new(a: Box<dyn SDF>, b: Box<dyn SDF>) -> Union {
        // ...
    }
}

// Another struct implements the trait SDF, which is hoped to be helpful
pub struct Sphere {
    center: Vec3f,
    radius: f32,
}

impl SDF for Sphere {
    fn distance(&self, p: Vec3f) -> f32 {
        (p - c).norm() - r
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I implement the `new` method?

Comment: Does Python needs to implement the trait or call its methods, or is it just opaque for Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expose `dyn Trait` directly to Python. You will have to create a wrapper.

Basically, create a `#[pyclass] pub struct DynSDF(Box<dyn SDF>);`. This is a normal pyclass you can access from Python.

Provide various constructors to it, each for each struct implementing the trait. For example, a constructor for `Sphere`, either taking `Sphere` directly (if it is a `#[pyclass]`, in this case it can also be `#[new]`), or a `sphere()` method taking as parameters what requires to build a `Sphere`.

If you also need to call the trait methods from Python, add `#[pymethods]` to `DynSDF` calling the trait methods.

Then, inside `Union::new()`, take `DynSDF`. Python can pass it since it is a Python class.